# Android: Get components of a child layout

Tags: android, view, arraylist

I have an *inflate view* that i add in a *LinearLayout* every time that click in a *"add"* button. This *view* have a lot of components (TextViews, Spinner ), so, how can i get the informations of the components of each view and put it on a object when other button *"confirm"* be clicked.

i try this, that i saw a similiar resolution here in StackOverflow :

```
    confirmRecord = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.btConfirmRecord );
    confirmRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {               
        ArrayList<ViewGroup> elementList = new ArrayList<ViewGroup>();

        for( int i = 0; i < listRecord.getChildCount(); i++ ){
           if( listRecord.getChildAt( i ) instanceof ViewGroup ){
            elementList.add( (ViewGroup) listRecord.getChildAt( i ) );
           }    
         }
        }
    });
```

but i don't know what i especifically got from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are unaware of the fact that `findViewById(int id)` can be called on a `View`.

Meaning, you can add ids to the views you need in the XML layout that you are inflating when add is pressed. And when confirm is pressed, you can get the views you need by calling `yourLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.bla)`.

Comment: The view that I add in layout, every time that add is pressed, is the same, it's like a ListView of this view, so the id is the same too.

Comment: Yes, if you are adding these view to the same Parent. You can loop through the children of this Parent(Each time getting an inflated view). Then you can use findViewById on each of these view to get the views that you need. This will work even if you have multiple views (With the same id) because you are calling findViewById on an individual parent.